# wso2am-1.10.0: ERROR - NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager

### WSO2 Api Manager's Carbon and Publisher Links Not Working

> After starting up wso2-am server as mentioned in its documentation:  [WSO2 API Manager Documentation / Running the Product](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Running+the+Product) only store link is working while accessing the other two components (i.e. carbon and publisher) following exception is occurring every time I'm hitting their URLs:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for AlgorithmParameters (provider: SunEC) cannot be found.
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1373)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:807)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:775)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:335)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:193)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for AlgorithmParameters (provider: SunEC) cannot be found.
    at sun.security.util.ECUtil.getECParameters(ECUtil.java:141)
    at sun.security.util.ECUtil.getCurveName(ECUtil.java:214)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getNamedCurveOid(JsseJce.java:389)
    at sun.security.ssl.SupportedEllipticCurvesExtension.getCurveIndex(SupportedEllipticCurvesExtension.java:161)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1011)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:884)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:213)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:936)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:876)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:873)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1313)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:285)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:343)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for AlgorithmParameters (provider: SunEC) cannot be found.
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1649)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1592)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
    at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:146)
    at sun.security.util.ECUtil.getECParameters(ECUtil.java:139)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.ec.ECParameters
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1636)
    ... 26 more
```

> I'm also getting the same exceptions with WSO2 Api Manager's latest version: **2.0.0**.
>
> Kindly show me how to tackle it and what's the main cause of such an exception. By the way I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate and JDK 1.8.

Comment: Can you verify that the java.policy file has the below snippet - grant codeBase "file:${{java.ext.dirs}}/*" { permission java.security.AllPermission; };

Comment: Are you using Oracle JDK or OpenJDK?